# Can not get the latest data after updated the user profile(vue.js 2, vuex, laravel 8)

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex, laravel-8

I'm a newbie in VueX. I face a problem which is after I updated the profile information and save it successfully, the database has shown the latest updated info but the user interfaces cannot retrieve the latest data. The state seems no updated.

My profile UI

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QtI9.png

but after updated, all the info disappear and didn't show the latest info

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul1ob.png

**UserProfile.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="container" style="padding-top:25px">
    <div class="main-font">My Profile</div>
    <div class="d-flex row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <ValidationObserver v-slot="{ handleSubmit }">
                <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit(updateProfile)">
                    <div class="d-flex py-4">                       
                        <div>                                
                            <img class="profile" src="/img/default.png" alt=""                               
                        </div>
                        <div class="my-auto ml-5">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn upload text"><i class="fas fa-upload fa-sm pr-2"></i>Upload new picture</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-10 p-0 m-0">
                        <ValidationProvider name="Name" rules="required|alpha" v-slot="{ errors }">
                            <label  class="text">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control form-text" placeholder="Enter your username" v-model="userForm.name">
                            <span class="error-messsage">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
                        </ValidationProvider>
                        <!-- <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-10 p-0 m-0 mt-4">
                        <ValidationProvider name="E-mail" rules="required|email" v-slot="{ errors }">
                            <label class="text">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" id="email"  class="form-control form-text" placeholder="Enter email" v-model="userForm.email">
                            <span class="error-messsage">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
                        </ValidationProvider>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn col-10 p-o save-but">SAVE CHANGES</button>
                </form>
            </ValidationObserver>
        </div>
        <div class="w-50">
            <img class="bg-img" src="/img/profile-bg.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
<script>
import { ValidationProvider, ValidationObserver, extend } from 'vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.full';

export default {

    components: {
        ValidationProvider,
        ValidationObserver,
    },

    data() {
        return {
            userForm: {
                name: '',
                email: '',  
            },
            
            error: null,
        }
    },
     
    created () {
        this.userForm = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.getters.currentUser));
    },

    computed: {          
        currentUser(){
            return this.$store.getters.currentUser;
        },
    },

    methods: {
        getUser (){
            const token = this.$store.getters.currentUser.token
            axios.get('/api/auth/userprofile',{
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
                this.userForm= response.data.user;
            })
        },

        updateProfile () {
            const token = this.$store.getters.currentUser.token
            // console.log(this.$store.getters.currentUser.token)
            axios.put('/api/auth/update-profile', 
                {
                name: this.userForm.name,    
                email: this.userForm.email,
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json" // add content-type
                }
            })
                .then(response => {
                    this.userForm.name = response.data.name;
                    this.userForm.email = response.data.email; 
                    swal({
                        icon: "success",
                        text: "Update Succesfully!",
                    });   
                    // this.$store.commit('update');
                })
        }
    }    
}
</script>
```

**store.js**

```
import {getLoggedinUser} from './auth';
import {getUser} from './auth';
const user = getLoggedinUser();
const updateUser = getUser();

export default {
    state: {
        currentUser: user,
        isLoggedin: !!user,
        loading: false,
        auth_error: null,
        reg_error:null,
        registeredUser: null,
        update: null,
    },
    getters: {
        isLoading(state){
        return state.loading;
        },
        isLoggedin(state){
            return state.isLoggedin;
        },
        currentUser(state){
            return state.currentUser;
        },
        authError(state){
            return state.auth_error;    
        },
        regError(state){
            return state.reg_error;
        },
        registeredUser(state){
            return state.registeredUser;
        },
        update(state){
            return state.update;
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        login(state){
            state.loading = true;
            state.auth_error = null;
        },
        loginSuccess(state, payload){
            state.auth_error = null;
            state.isLoggedin = true;
            state.loading = false;
            state.currentUser = Object.assign({}, payload.user , {token: payload.access_token});
            localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(state.currentUser));
        },
        loginFailed(state, payload){
            state.loading = false;
            state.auth_error = payload.error;
        },
        logout(state){
            localStorage.removeItem("user");
            state.isLoggedin = false;
            state.currentUser = null;
        },
        registerSuccess(state, payload){
            state.reg_error = null;
            state.registeredUser = payload.user;
        },
        registerFailed(state, payload){
            state.reg_error = payload.error;
        },
        update(state, payload) {
            state.currentUser = payload.data;      
        }
    },
    actions: {
        login(context){
            context.commit("login");
        },
        // update(context){
        //     // state.currentUser.update(context);
        // }

    }
};
```

**auth.js**

```
export function registerUser(credentials){
  return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
      axios.post('/api/auth/register', credentials)
      .then(response => {
          res(response.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
          rej('An error occured.. try again later.')
      })
  })
}

export function login(credentials){
  return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
      axios.post('/api/auth/login', credentials)
      .then(response => {
            setAuthorization(response.data.access_token);
            res(response.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
          rej('Wrong Email/Password combination.')
      })
  })
}

export function getLoggedinUser(){
  const userStr = localStorage.getItem('user');

  if(!userStr){
      return null
  }

  return JSON.parse(userStr);
}

export function getUser(credentials){
  return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
    axios.get('/api/auth/userprofile', credentials)
    .then(response => {
          // setAuthorization(response.data.access_token);
          res(response.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        rej('No User')
    })
})
}
```

Please help me if you have any ideas or solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're not running any dispatches of your store.

You have defined `update` mutation, but commented it.

Uncomment this

```js
// this.$store.commit('update')
```

and modify it like so:

```js
this.$store.commit('update', { data: response.data })
```

Next do the same for your login request.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. Could you please guide me on what should I do in store.js if you are convenient? Cause I am still confusing about it. For your information, the vuex code gets from a tutorial website, but I still not familiar with it.